# To find a symmetric operator that is not essentially self-adjoint under some conditions.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

There is a theorem saying:

If a symmetric operator $A$ (in the Hilbert space $h$) satisfies $Ran(A+z) = Ran(A+\bar z) = h,$  for some $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $A$ is self-adjoint.

However, this theorem implies that when symmetric operator $A$ satisfies merely that $Ran(A+z)$ and $Ran(A+\bar z)$ are $\textit{dense}$ in $h$, then $A$ is not necessarily self-adjoint. In fact, I suspect that $A$ is neither $\textit{essentially self-adjoint}.$ In that case, $D(A)$ cannot be dense.

To supplement my reasoning, I want to find proper $\textit{example}$ of it. 
Are there well-known examples? It would be nice if someone could help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: ["If A is a symmetric operator on H, then A is essentially self-adjoint if and only if the range of the operators  A-i￼ and  A+i are dense in H."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Extensions_of_symmetric_operators)